# Support for encoding query string or POST data in YUI?

Tags: javascript, ajax, yui

How do you encode a javascript object/hash (pairs of properties and values) into a URL-encoded query string with YUI (2.7.0 or 3.0.0 Beta) ?

I want to do the equivalent of [Object.toQueryString()](http://prototypejs.org/api/object/toquerystring) from Prototype:

I need this to encode parameters for GET and POST requests with YAHOO.util.Connect.

It turns out YAHOO.util.Connect has a setForm() method to serialize a form but that still leaves me out cold to encode parameters for GET requests, or the 4th parameter of YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest() to pass post data.

Answer (score 2):

I've made this little helper for my own project.

```
var toQueryString = function(o) {
    if(typeof o !== 'object') {
        return false;
    }
    var _p, _qs = [];
    for(_p in o) {
        _qs.push(encodeURIComponent(_p) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(o[_p]));
    }
    return _qs.join('&');
};

// And to use it
var qs = toQueryString({'foo' : 'bar'});
```

Answer (score 0):

YUI3 has the io-form module, which you can instantiate in your call the use. It allows you to write code like this:

```
YUI().use('node', 'io-form', function(Y) {
 Y.get('#formId').on('sumbit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        Y.io(postURL,
        {
            method: "POST",
            on: {
                complete: on_complete_handler
            },
            form: {
                id: "formId"
            }
        });
    }
});
```

This code will make a POST request to postURL, with all the input values from the form with id "formId" is submitted. This module also works for GET requests.

Comment: My question is about encoding a javascript hash/Object. Regarding form, YUI 2.7.0  Connection Manager provides a setForm() method.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using something like this based on some code found on github. The function must handle posting arrays..

"Y" is a reference to "YAHOO"

```
    /**
     * Turns an object into its URL-encoded query string representation.
     *
     * @param {Object} obj   Parameters as properties and values 
     */
    toQueryString: function(obj, name) {

        var i, l, s = [];

        if (Y.lang.isNull(obj) || Y.lang.isUndefined(obj)) {
        return name ? encodeURIComponent(name) + '=' : '';
      }

        if (Y.lang.isBoolean(obj)) {
        obj = obj ? 1 : 0;
      }

      if (Y.lang.isNumber(obj) || Y.lang.isString(obj)) {
        return encodeURIComponent(name) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(obj);
      }

      if (Y.lang.isArray(obj)) {
        name = name; // + '[]'; don't do this for Java (php thing)
        for (i = 0, l = obj.length; i < l; i ++) {
          s.push(arguments.callee(obj[i], name));
        }
        return s.join('&');
      }

      // now we know it's an object.
      var begin = name ? name + '[' : '',
          end = name ? ']' : '';
      for (i in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            s.push(arguments.callee(obj[i], begin + i + end));
        }
      }

      return s.join("&");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see YUILibrary [Ticket 2528174](http://yuilibrary.com/projects/yui3/ticket/2528174) refers to an accepted [contribution](http://github.com/isaacs/yui3/tree/master/src/querystring) on for this.

```
The Querystring Utility
    Provides static methods to serialize objects to querystrings and deserialize objects from querystrings.

    Three modules are available:
        querystring           - Both parse and stringify functionality
        querystring-parse     - Parse valid querystring into JavaScript objects
        querystring-stringify - Serialize JavaScript objects into valid query strings
```